# WebRTC video doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

Good day!
I do audio / video chat using WebRTC technologies, but I have 1 problem with my WebRTC video chat.

That's what I'm doing:

1. I have function startCall();

   1.1 Getting User Media

   1.2 Create Local RTCPeerConnection

   1.3 Send Offer (Laravel-echo-server)
2. The same thing for the remote user, only he sends the answer

   It works great, but when I try to add a track to a video, the remote user does not play the video

```
    In Local User: 

    handleEnableCamera(isCaller) {
     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
      this.stream.addTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
      this.$refs.localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      this.rtc.peerConnection.addTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0], stream);
      this.sendOffer('video');
     });
    }
```

```
   Events In Remote User: 
   Send Answer and listen Event

    this.rtc.peerConnection.ontrack = e => {
     if (e.track.kind === 'video') {
      this.$refs.remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
     } else {
      this.$refs.remoteAudio.srcObject = e.streams[0];
     }
    };
```

Local Video work fine.

e.streams[0] have video Track but doesn't work

i have onloadedmetadata for elements for play video

Comment: I think you need to send offer and answer on both machines (4 requests) unless you want to send video in one direction. (I'm not sure if this is not requirement to have connection at all). You also need something called "ice" message on connection. Stun and Turn servers are also required with WebRTC one of them is only required if you test of two different machines (not in two tabs in same browser).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try on different machine